# url_for raises BuildError, but view with that name and arguments exists

Tags: python, flask

I want to add autocomplete to a text field.  However, when I try to use `url_for` to pass the autocomplete url to JavaScript, I get `werkzeug.routing.BuildError BuildError: ('autocomplete', {}, None)`.

Priting out `app.url_map` shows `<Rule '/autocomplete' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> autocomplete>`.

How do I fix this error?

```
@app.route('/autocomplete',methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    URL = 'http://www.amis.pk/DistrictCities.aspx'
    City_Data = scrape(URL)
    City_Data = sorted(City_Data, key=lambda x: x.name)
    return jsonify(json_list=City_Data)
```

```
{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted your template code and javascript code (or just the ajax part that uses the url). If you are using a separate `javascript` file to handle the autocomplete, make sure to create the javascript url variable in your template inside a `<script>` tag since `javascript` files cannot render Jinja variables or flask variables

Comment: If you are using a separate javascript file to handle the autocomplete, make sure to create the javascript url variable in your template inside a <script> tag since javascript files cannot render Jinja variables or flask variables
^ could you explain this part a little more please?